# ValueError: Layer MLP_Model expects 1 input(s), but it received 460 input tensors. (At Dense layer)

Tags: python, keras

I have a trouble in my MLP model in Keras.

```
def create_model():
    MLP_model = tf.keras.Sequential(name='MLP_Model')
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(208,)))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    MLP_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16))
    MLP_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mse', 'accuracy'])
    MLP_model.summary()
    return MLP_model

print(np.shape(x_train))
print(np.shape(y_train))
stage2_model = create_model()
stage2_model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.3, epochs=1, batch_size=18, verbose=1)
test_scores = stage2_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test Loss : ", test_scores[0])
print("Test Accuracy : ", test_scores[1])
```

Here's my code. The result of `print(np.shape(x_train))` and `print(np.shape(y_train))` outcomes like

```
(460, 208)
(460, 16)
```

which `460` is size of data, `208` and `16` are size of x and y respectively. (They are 1D array, definitely not a 2D)

Thrown error is

```
ValueError: Layer MLP_Model expects 1 input(s), but it received 460 input tensors.
```

I tried lot of modification of data shape, but it didn't work anyway.

How should I revise it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: generally, Sequential model doesn't need Input layer... try to remove it and set input_shape=(208,) in your first Dense

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work when I removed input layer.

Comment: simply not possible :-) https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WLiNwG5FtFQhcsh1mMGSSWmnqHc_Vxwm?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing code! But it doesn't work on my pycharm... ToT...